# How to Convert specific Tds of a specific row of a table into Text Box so their values can be edited

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, onclick

So, I have a table as given below:

```
<table border='1' id="table" style="color: #004080;">
  <tr>
    <th >EmpID</th>
    <th >EmpName</th>
    <th >EmpDesignation</th>
    <th >Edit</th>
    <th >Del</th>
    </tr>

   <?php
        foreach($result->result() as $row)
        { 
   ?>          
            <tr  >
                <td >
                    <?php 
                        echo $row->EmpID
                    ?>
                </td >
                <td  >
                    <?php
                        echo $row->EmpName;
                    ?>
                </td> 
                <td >
                    <?php
                        echo $row->EmpDesignation;
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td >
                   <img src="editicon.png" id="Edit" /> 
                </td>
                <td >
                    <img src="Delicon.png" onclick="Del(this)" /> 
                </td>
         </tr>  
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Now what I want to do is to write a jQuery function against a click event of Edit Image which i put on each row at 4th Column

I successfully pop up the alert but I want the corresponding jQuery to make tds at position 2 and 3 against a Clicked Edit Image(for Specific Row, this.row etc) turn into a text box so I can change their values
My jQuery func. is given below

```
$('#Edit').live('click', function () {
    alert('inside edit image click func');      
    // write Jquery Func here
});
```

Thank You :)

Comment: Nbrooks's is also R8, try this one also - add claas or ID to that tr and then target using class/ID

Comment: Thanks
But How can i assign a unique ID to each row since they are inside a foreach loop???

Comment: @Ali, you don't need a unique ID for each one...in fact, that would make it harder for you.  Just use a class, as I demonstrate in my answer

Comment: Notice that ` <img src="editicon.png" id="Edit" /> ` is a problem. IDs must be unique.

Comment: Now i got it
thank You Sir :)

Comment: Thank You Sir
i tried clicking up arrow
but it says "Vote UP requires 15 reputation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML IDs must be unique, so you can't duplicate the element with id `#Edit`; make it a class instead `class='Edit'`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Older version: $('#table').delegate('.Edit', 'click', function() { */
    $('#table').on('click', '.Edit', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1), td:eq(2)').each(function() {
            // replace the existing text with a textbox containing that text
            var existingVal = $(this).text();
            $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + existingVal + '" >');
        });
    });


    // when the user is finished editing, change the value and remove the textbox
    /* Older version: $('#table').delegate('td input', 'focusout', function() {*/
    $('#table').on('focusout', 'td input', function() {
        $(this).parent().html( this.value );
    });
});
```

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated; notice that I use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead

You have to change the html for the image to:

```
<img src="editicon.png" class="Edit" />
```

Comment: @ali did you change your html as well? and by not working, what do you mean? Sorry, also added another quick fix, try it again.

Comment: i put an alert("Here") inside your function and unfortunately it is not showing alert..

Comment: @Ali which version of jQuery are you using? This function requires jq 1.7. Also, You need to change both the javascript *and* the html for it to work, have you done that?

Comment: i am using jquery 1.6.2 :(
i have done everything you told me, now i guess the lower version of jquery is making problem for me

Comment: @Ali Ok that's why the function never fired. If there's no reason for using the older jQuery, you should go ahead and update to the latest version. Otherwise, I added an alternative technique for older versions to my answer. :)

Comment: i have downloaded jquery latest version
can you tell me Plz where should i placed it( in which directory) i am using code igniter with wamp server
Moment ago i was doing like this
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">

Comment: @ali You can (more or less) include it anywhere in your html. No need to download anything, just include `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your php/html code

Comment: @ali I should clarify by saying that jQuery must be included before any other scripts relying on it, so it's often found in the `<head>`; it is used so often and cached by the browser, so that shouldn't affect page load time -- so safest in `<head>`

Comment: no i mean i which computer directory
like D:\wamp\www etc
cos yet it is throwing 404 page not found error

Comment: Finally it is working
Thanks a lot nbrooks
May God Bless You Ameen :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Use jQuery to replace the td value with an input, or
2. Have the input already there (but hidden).

While it makes the page bigger, I find method #2 faster and more stable. It works like this:

**CSS:**

```
.inputs { display: none; }
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
    $(this).parent('tr').find('.values').hide();
    $(this).parent('tr').find('.inputs').show();
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<table><?
foreach ($result->result() as $row) {
echo '
    <tr id="row_'. $row->id .'">
        <td><span class="values">'. $row->EmpID .'</span>
            <span class="inputs"><input name="EmpID" value="'. $row->EmpID .'"></span>
            </td>
        <td><span class="values">'. $row->EmpName .'</span>
            <span class="inputs"><input name="EmpName" value="'. $row->EmpName .'"></span>
            </td>
        <td><img class="edit" src="editicon.png"></td>
        <td><img class="del" src="delicon.png"></td>
    </tr>';
?></table>
```

I then use another jQuery call to look for changes in .inputs, get the row id from the `<tr>`, and update the db via ajax.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your

> i want ... to make tds at position 2 and 3 a turn into a text box so i can change their values

try using the [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) plugin. The [demo page](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html) should give you an idea if this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

First, use the `.on()` method (or `.delegate()`, especially for jQuery before 1.7), rather than the `.live()` method, because the latter has been deprecated.

Second, don't use an id for the edit icon.  Change is so that rather than saying `id="Edit"`, say `class="Edit"`.  Your code, as it currently stands, makes multiple ids, which is a violation of HTML DOM and causes unpredictable behavior in browsers.

```
<table border='1' id="table" style="color: #004080;">
  <tr>
    <th>EmpID</th>
    <th>EmpName</th>
    <th>EmpDesignation</th>
    <th>Edit</th>
    <th>Del</th>
  </tr>

  <?php foreach($result->result() as $row) { ?>          
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row->EmpID ?></td> 
      <td><?php echo $row->EmpName; ?></td> 
      <td><?php echo $row->EmpDesignation; ?></td>
      <td><img src="editicon.png" class="Edit" /></td>
      <td><img src="Delicon.png" onclick="Del(this)" /></td>
    </tr>  
  <?php } ?>

</table>
```

That said, you know the item that was clicked, so just traverse up to the `tr`, then down to the relevant `td`s, and change the html inside the `td` to an inputbox:

```
$('#table').delegate('.Edit','click', function () {
    $(this).parent('tr').find('td:eq(1), td:eq(2)').each(function () {
        $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + $(this).html() + "' />");
    }
});
```

This will change the columns on that row into input boxes and pre-fill them with the information already present in the cell.

Comment: Oh i got it
Thanks
btw i like your method of explaining all this stuff
thanks again :)

Comment: @Ali, I've updated my code to show using `delegate`, which is good for any version of jQuery.

Comment: Sir can you tell me where to place a jquery latest downloaded script in which directory??
i am using codeigniter with wamp server
Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't know directly, because I don't know your file structure.  However, you can just use [Google's Hosted files](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) by adding this line to your HTML head: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#Edit').click(function () {
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.editable').each(function(){

    var currentVal = $(this).text();
    $(this).html("<input type='text' value='"+ currentVal +"'>")
  });
});
```

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsalama/E4cNb/1/)